# How comes this code works in groovy?

Tags: groovy

How comes that it is possible to write `this.class` in the fields declaration of a class and it will actually do what is expected?

E.g.:

```
private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(this.class)
```

P.S.: Seems like a great place for Schroedinbug. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Groovy `this` is bound to the class in a static context, and you can call static methods on it. `Logger.getLogger(this.class)` would be equivalent to just `Logger.getLogger(Class)`.

```
class C {
    static final staticThis = this
    static final thisClass  = this.getClass()
    static final someResult = this.someMethod()

    static someMethod() { 'static' }
}

assert C.staticThis == C.class
assert C.thisClass  == Class
assert C.someResult == C.someMethod()
```

Comment: Groovy is actually full of surprises. Used this.class for every class and only after a while it started pointing out that this.class might be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Justin's answer is correct, in a static context `this` is bound to the `Class` object of the current class, Therefore, you can replace the code above with:

```
private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(this)
```

which you can safely copy-paste from one class to another, unlike:

```
private static final logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class)
```